# Homeomorphisms are equivalence relations, so what are the equivalence classes?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, equivalence-relations

Homeomorphisms are equivalence relations, so what are the equivalence classes for two Topological spaces $T_1, T_2$?

Intuitively it seems like we might have the following equivalence classes -

1. Functions that are homeomorphisms between both spaces
2. Functions that are not homeomorphisms between both spaces

But that's probably not correct. So can someone clarify for me what are the equivalence classes here, ie. how the spaces are partitioned?

Comment: Homeomorphisms give an equivalence relation between spaces, not a relation on the spaces themselves. The equivalence classes are sets of spaces which are "equivalent" topologically (i.e. the spaces that are homeomorphic). I'm not sure what equivalence relation it is you're trying to put on functions between spaces.

Comment: You are mixing a few things,  so that what you wrote does not make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

Define a relation on the collection of all topological spaces by $T\sim S$ iff there exists a homeomorphism $h:T\to S$.  It is easy to see that this relation is reflexive and symmetric (any space is homeomorphic to itself via the identity map, and use $h^{-1}$ is a homeomorphism $S\to T$).  Transitivity will follow by simply taking compositions of homeomorphisms.  Thus we have an equivalence relation.  An equivalence class under this relation will by a maximal collection of topological spaces which are mutually homeomorphic.